# Extract MIN MAX of SQL table in python

Tags: python, sql, pymssql

I have a db with the following info:

```
+----+------+-----+-----+------+------+-----------+    
| id | time | lat | lon | dep  | dest |  reg      |    
+----+------+-----+-----+------+------+-----------+    
| a  |    1 |  10 |  20 | home | work | alpha     |    
| a  |    6 |  11 |  21 | home | work | alpha     |    
| a  |   11 |  12 |  22 | home | work | alpha     |    
| b  |    2 |  70 |  80 | home | cine | beta      |    
| b  |    8 |  70 |  85 | home | cine | beta      |    
| b  |   13 |  70 |  90 | home | cine | beta      |    
+----+------+-----+-----+------+------+-----------+
```

Is it possible to extract the following info:

```
+----+------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+------+--------+    
| id | tmin | tmax | lat_tmin | lon_tmin | lat_tmax | lon_tmax | dep  | dest |   reg  |    
+----+------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+------+--------+    
| a  |    1 |   11 |       10 |       20 |       12 |       22 | home | work | alpha  |    
| b  |    2 |   13 |       70 |       80 |       70 |       90 | home | cine | beta   |    
+----+------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+------+--------+
```

what if dep & dest were varying - how would tou select them?

Thks

Comment: my first question should be: how do you format tables :-)

Comment: *"what if dep & dest were varying"*: what do you want to have in the result in that case? Can you add that info to your question? NB: I don't think you should tag this as a python question, unless you generally don't know how to do SQL queries from python... but that is a different question (with lots of info [on the internet](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/pymssql_examples.html)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a window function for that:

```
SELECT     t0.id,
           t0.time as     tmin, t1.time as     tmax,
           t0.lat  as lat_tmin, t1.lat  as lat_tmax,
           t0.lon  as lon_tmin, t1.lon  as lon_tmax,
           t0.dep,
           t0.dest,
           t0.reg
FROM       ( SELECT *, 
                    row_number() over (partition by id order by time asc) as rn
             FROM   t) AS t0
INNER JOIN ( SELECT *, 
                    row_number() over (partition by id order by time desc) as rn
             FROM   t) AS t1
        ON t0.id = t1.id
WHERE      t0.rn = 1 
       AND t1.rn = 1
```

This will return the data from the first and last row for each *id*, when sorted by *id*, *time*.

The values for *dep*, *dest* and *reg* are taken from the first row (per *id*) only.

If you want to also have separate rows for when -- for the same *id* -- you have different values of *dep* or *dest*, then just add those in the `partition by` clauses. All depends on which output you expect in that case:

```
SELECT     t0.id,
           t0.time as     tmin, t1.time as     tmax,
           t0.lat  as lat_tmin, t1.lat  as lat_tmax,
           t0.lon  as lon_tmin, t1.lon  as lon_tmax,
           t0.dep,
           t0.dest,
           t0.reg           
FROM       ( SELECT *, 
                    row_number() over (partition by id, dep, dest, reg 
                                       order by time asc) as rn
             FROM   t) AS t0
INNER JOIN ( SELECT *, 
                    row_number() over (partition by id, dep, dest, reg 
                                       order by time desc) as rn
             FROM   t) AS t1
        ON t0.id = t1.id
WHERE      t0.rn = 1 
       AND t1.rn = 1
```

Please consider using a different name for the column `time` because of [this remark in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx#Anchor_1):

> The following keywords could be reserved in future releases of SQL Server as new features are implemented. Consider avoiding the use of these words as identifiers.
>
> ```
> ... TIME ...
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(t.time) as tmin, max(t.time) as tmax, (...) from table_name t group by t.dest
```

(...) just repeat for the other columns